# Has there been any program to develop tiny pod-like vehicles with manipulator arms for extra-vehicular activities?

Tags: eva, orbital-assembly, maintenance

Remember the pressurized repair / assembly pods from 2001 A Space Odyssey and so many other space visionary works? Has there been any programs to design & build tiny vehicles like that with manipulator arms, for space stations or construction in space?

[image: EVA pod]

Comment: Pressurized? That implies you mean manned vehicles?

Comment: Yes manned. Maybe some free flying robot systems would be interesting too, but I am mostly interested if any space program or industry took the idea further.

Comment: Currently, in the age of drones, unmanned remote-controlled "helper robots" are far more viable and practical. Adding a small spacecraft around the astronaut gives very small benefits over an EVA suit, while seriously increasing mass and cost.

Comment: Von Braun's "bottle suit" from the fifties? [picture](https://archive.org/details/MSFC-9605274)

Answer (score 3):

There has been at least one [semi-recent (2012) paper](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20120016580.pdf) on the topic.  The design is called the Flexcraft. There is a wikipedia article [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FlexCraft).

[image]

It appears to be purely in the proposal stage.

The concept was more common in the '50s and '60s.  You can see a lot of concept art at the wonderful [Atomic Rockets](http://www.projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/spacesuits.php) page (search the page for "A space pod is a small pressurized vehicle" - the page is gigantic).

Comment: This is great. It seem as though it is being considered for the deep space missions to asteroids and such. They make a very good point that if there is an emergency or other urgent need you can't just jump in a space suit because you need decompression time. For this you don't. In spit of robots it still makes a lot of sense.